# Python fit_transform return only zeros

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to fit_transform an Numpy array, but when run `fit_transfort()`,
it will fill only zero values.

```
data = [[3],[9],[3],[12],[3],[8],[8],[13],[12],[2],[0],['42'],['58'],[12],[12],[6],[3],[6],[4],[7],[10]];

data=np.array(data).reshape(1, -1)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

data_fit = scaler.fit_transform(data) 

pred_prova=ll.predict(data_fit)

X_test_std[0] # <---- it is right and return from X_train_std = ss.fit_transform(X_train)
```

> array([-0.23130257,  0.19945477, -0.49045489, -2.40903789,  0.62833204, ........

```
data_fit
```

> array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
> 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `reshape` the data before `fit_transform`, do it afterwards

```
data = [[3],[9],[3],[12],[3],[8],[8],[13],[12],[2],[0],['42'],['58'],[12],[12],[6],[3],[6],[4],[7],[10]]

data=np.array(data)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

data_fit = scaler.fit_transform(data)

pred_prova=ll.predict(data_fit)

X_test_std[0] # <---- it is right and return from X_train_std = ss.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Comment: The mixed types are actually handled by the scaler. It casts to nunmeric

Comment: Also the model will presumably expect that 2D shape. So that shouldn't be changed

Comment: Thank you just realized that reshape(-1,1) does nothing to a 2D array.